# How to delete data from multiple tables in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to delete data from AssetType table and TypeProperties table. I can delete data of AssetType table, but TypeProperties is not. And it appears the following error :

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.

```php
function deleteType($id)
 {
      $type = AssetType::find($id)->delete();
      $property = TypeProperties::where('assettype_id', $type->id)->get()->delete();
      return redirect(url('assettype'));
  }
```

Comment: delete the `typeproperty` first then the `assetype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the `AssetType`. you can delete from both tables using the `$id` that you are passing to the function.

```php
function deleteType($id)
{
    AssetType::where('id', $id)->delete();
    TypeProperties::where('assettype_id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect(url('assettype'));
}
```

Comment: it's useful for me. I did it. Thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set this up in your migrations:

`$table->foreign('assettype_id')->references('id')->on('assettypes')->onDelete('cascade');`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

> You may also specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on
>   update" properties of the constraint:
>
> ```
> $table->foreign('assettype_id')
>       ->references('id')->on('assettypes')
>       ->onDelete('cascade');
> ```